# go to beginning of for statement in java

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java and maybe my question is a bit irritating.

I have two `for` loops in my code and I want to go to the beginning of each one by a `for`-`else` statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] x=new int[1000][1000];

    int[] Z=new int[1000];

    lable1:
        for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++)
        {
            Z[i]=rand1.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println("Z["+i +"] = " + Z[i] );

            if(Z[i]>0 && Z[i]<=Nk)
            {
                int Z1=Z[i]-1;
                lable2:         
                    for(int j = 1; j<=Z1;j++ )
                    {
                        x[i][j]= rand2.nextInt(1000);
                        sum+=x[i][j];
                        if( sum<1000)
                        {
                            x[i][(j+1)]=1000-sum;
                            System.out.println("x[" + i+"][" + j + "] = " + x[i][j]);
                            System.out.println("Nx[" + i+"][" + (j+1) + "] = " +x[i][(j+1)]);
                        }
                        else{
                            // ????
                            //Goto lable2;
                        }
                    }
            }
            else{
                //goto label1;
                // ????
            } 
        }

}
```

Comment: Please, make your code readable before asking a question =). It's very difficult to understand it.

Comment: Nice use of random indentations

Comment: Tried using `continue`??

Comment: With the code as it is now, just remove both `else` blocks.

Comment: *"im very new to java and maybe my question is a bit irritating. i h"*  Not sure about your question since I could not manage to read it.  The reason I could not read it is because 'mumbling' in all lower case gives me a head-ache.  If your keyboard has a working  shift key, use it, if not, fix it.

Comment: One mini answer. The for dont start on 1 and end on <= . Start on 0 and end on <

Comment: Instead of `for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)` you should have used `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)`

Answer (score 6):

You can `break` to any defined label (within scope) by using:

```
break label;
```

Same holds for `continue`.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) is something to read.

In your particular example, removing the `else`s would do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `continue` keyword.. It will continue with the next iteration.. **No need to label your loop**.. As you are not continuing the outer loop from the inner one.. Or, if you want to `continue` with outer loop, you can use `continue` with a **label**...

And you should use your for loop from `j = 0 to j < z1`..

```
for(int j = 0; j < Z1;j++ ) {    
      if( sum<1000) {
           x[i][(j+1)]=1000-sum;
           System.out.println("x[" + i+"][" + j + "] = " + x[i][j]);
           System.out.println("Nx[" + i+"][" + (j+1) + "] = " +x[i][(j+1)]);
       }
       else{  // Not needed if your else does not contain anything else..
           continue;
       }
}
```

In fact you don't need an **`else` block** at all.. If you are not doing any further processing in it..

Just remove it.. It will automatically go to your loop..

**Suggestion**: - You should use coding convention.. variable names start with `lowercase letter` or `underscore`.. (Z1 -> z1)

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] x = new int[1000][1000];

        int[] Z = new int[1000];

        boolean resetOuterCycle = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Z[i] = rand1.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println("Z[" + i + "] = " + Z[i]);

            if (Z[i] > 0 && Z[i] <= Nk) {
                int Z1 = Z[i] - 1;

                boolean resetInnerCycle = true;

                for (int j = 0; j < Z1; j++) {
                    x[i][j] = rand2.nextInt(1000);
                    sum += x[i][j];
                    if (sum < 1000) {
                        x[i][(j + 1)] = 1000 - sum;
                        System.out.println("x[" + i + "][" + j + "] = " + x[i][j]);
                        System.out.println("Nx[" + i + "][" + (j + 1) + "] = " + x[i][(j + 1)]);
                    } else if (resetInnerCycle) {
                        j = 0;
                        resetInnerCycle = false;
                    }
                }
            } else if (resetOuterCycle) {
                i = 0;
                resetOuterCycle = false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: i have tried continue. it doesnt work in this case. look I want to go to the beginning of the loop if the condition in else was true. Plz help me

Comment: so you need to set `i` back to `zero`?

Comment: YES somehow, I want the loop start from the 0

Comment: You can use `break label;` syntax or you can set initial value to a counter variable `i = 0;`

Comment: set counter j with 0 doesnt work. the cod goes to infinit loop. any idea plz?

Comment: you need to set it with 0(or to go to the beginning of the cycle) only once?
Then use some boolean flag. See edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**-** In your above code you can use 2 approach to do it...

**1st Approach :** No `else` part

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

   if (Z[i] > 0 && Z[i] <= Nk){
    for (int j = 0; j < Z1; j++) {

          if(sum < 1000){


         }
      }
    }
  }
```

**2nd Approach :** With `else` part and `continue`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

   if (Z[i] > 0 && Z[i] <= Nk){

    for (int j = 0; j < Z1; j++) {

              if(sum < 1000){


             }else{

                  continue;

             }
          }
       }else{

               continue;

        }
   }
```